# Cannot query GCS bucket using StorageAdmin role with conditions

Tags: google-cloud-storage, roles, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have created a service account with a `roles/storage.admin` role on it with the following condition:

```
resource.name.startsWith(
  "//storage.googleapis.com/projects/_/buckets/rakibs-new-bucket"
)
```

However, when this service account tries to query anything in the bucket it says the following:

`Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: googleapi: Error 403: my-new-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to rakibs-new-bucket., forbidden`

---

For reference: I followed [this gcloud doc link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/full-resource-names) to construct the resource name of the GCS bucket in the role condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned that the domain part was not necessary. Just ommitting the `//storage.googleapis.com/` part worked.

```
resource.name.startsWith(
  "projects/_/buckets/rakibs-new-bucket"
)
```